# Table Row terminating error with Emmet

Tags: html, emmet

What am I doing wrong in the below emmet? The first tr does not terminate properly. I trying searching the net but couldn't find anything. thank you

```
table>tr>td*3+tr*3>td*3>{Sample Data $}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you made second  `tr` to be a sibling of first `td`. You should either move second `tr` up with `^` operator:

`table>tr>td*3^tr*3>td*3>{Sample Data $}`

...or group rows

`table>(tr>td*3)(tr*3>td*3>{Sample Data $})`

Comment: The first one is exactly what I'm looking for, I need the first table row to contain the table header.  I made a typo but your answer provides me with the solution to my problem.  This is what I needed: table>tr>th*3^tr*3>td*3>{Sample Data $}

Answer (score 0):

where the Emmet render the html table `table>tr>td*3+tr*3>td*3>{Sample Data $}`
 was wrong because it renders as

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <tr>
   <td>Sample Data 1</td>
   <td>Sample Data 2</td>
   <td>Sample Data 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Sample Data 1</td>
   <td>Sample Data 2</td>
   <td>Sample Data 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Sample Data 1</td>
   <td>Sample Data 2</td>
   <td>Sample Data 3</td>
  </tr>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Where the dom is breaking, so please update as `table>tr*3>td{Sample Data $}*3`, it will render as

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Sample Data 1</td>
  <td>Sample Data 2</td>
  <td>Sample Data 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Sample Data 1</td>
  <td>Sample Data 2</td>
  <td>Sample Data 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Sample Data 1</td>
  <td>Sample Data 2</td>
  <td>Sample Data 3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```